# How is money in a Roth IRA classified as either "earnings" or "contribution" (basis)?

Tags: united-states, retirement, roth-ira

I have heard that if you withdraw money from your Roth early, there is no penalty or tax as long as it is a "contribution". However "earnings" cannot be withdrawn early without paying tax and 10% penalty. When I put money into my Roth how will it be classified as earnings or a contribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deposits are contributions.
You deposit say, $5000, and over time you have $6000. 
The $5000 can be withdrawn any time with no issue. It's tracked via [form 8606](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8606.pdf).

With this in mind, I wrote an article [The Roth Emergency Fund](http://rothmania.net/roth-emergency-fund/), suggesting that since one can withdraw deposits with no issue, the Roth can be used to hold emergency money.

Comment: Oh I see I was thinking about this completely incorrectly. So every amount you personally put in (contribution) you can take out without penalty. Any money gained through interest (earnings) cannot be taken out without penalty before 59.5 years of age.

Comment: Yes - See edit above. Just to reinforce the point.

Comment: Could you explain what happens if you *lose* money in the roth?  I deposit $1000 but I lose $500 every year for 5 years.  Then a year of $5000 gain?  Can I still withdraw $5K

Comment: @MrChrister - Yes, 8606 doesn't care what happened in between.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer is there a minimum amount of time to have a Roth open before even contributions can be pulled out? For example do you have to have your Roth account for 5 years before you can pull out contributions penalty free? Also what about the risk of associating an emergency fund with something that could decline in value like many of these funds in 2008?

Comment: @MrChrister How does one deposit $1000 and lose $500 every year for 5 years? After 2 years, your account will be closed!  But losing $50 per year for 5 years makes a lot more sense, and if you really have $750 left after losing $250 over 5 years and then have a gain of $5000, you cannot withdraw $5000 without penalty; only $1000 can be withdrawn without penalty.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think he meant every year he deposited 1000 again. Not a one time 1000 deposit. I got confused reading that at first also.

Comment: also @JoeTaxpayer how liquid is a Roth? How quickly could I withdraw my contribution emergency amount and have it in my bank account in the case of an emergency?

Comment: @AdamJohns - no minimum time. My emergency Roth concept is not to treat your retirement account like an emergency fund, but rather, if one's 401(k) is enough, and they wouldn't otherwise use Roth, putting liquid emergency money into a Roth is a no risk option. It's not invested in stocks, but the same as any emergency money, money market, CDs, Tbills. Money market is liquid, same or next day withdrawal depending on broker.